# How to avoid mixing SVG colors without using ClipPath?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

I have two SVG paths, path-B (green colored) is strictly a sub-set of path-A (red-colored).  When I plot them together, path-B becomes black because green+red=black!  I'd like to have path-B's color overwrites path-A instead of mixing.  How can I achieve that?  I know I can use ClipPath to do that, but this is a simplified version, the real case involves dozens of segments and there might be a path-C which is a subset of path-B and so on so forth.  I want the next path's color overwrites previous ones.  Can anyone please direct me if there's such settings in SVG or CSS to accomplish that?  Thank you very much!

BTW, I used D3 to generate SVG paths.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit: there was this `style="mix-blend-mode: multiply;"` line sneaked in my code.  Once I remove it, everything works as expected.

Comment: Aha! - FWIW - there is no z-index in SVG, whatever gets drawn last in order goes on top.